# Is it a good Idea to log queries and tables?

Tags: security, owasp

Is it a good Idea to throw exceptions in error log with following information:
-queries 
-tables

```
$this->_conn->rethrowException($e, $this, $this->_stmt->queryString, $params);
```

Answer (score 0):

It really depends, if you return the exception message back to the user, you're exposing information about you're DB scheme and the queries you're running. This information could be valuable for hackers :)

Comment: it is not going back to the user. this is in our internal logs

Comment: As long as you can be sure about that - it's not too bad. Just careful with what you log - so you will not accidentally log user data :) For example, don't log queries with the values of the parameters...